# capture sqoop output in oozie

Tags: sqoop, oozie

I have an Oozie workflow which is supposed to run every X minutes. It reads a value from an HBase table. After this a Sqoop action is run (incremental) based on the value read from HBase in the previous step. To make the workflow work I need to somehow capture the new --last-value from the Sqoop Oozie action to be written back to HBase and the next time the workflow runs to read it again... and so on.

How can I do this, or might there be a better way?

Jonas

Comment: Sqoop doesn't support it out of the box for now, you have to update the property file yourself at this stage. But personally, I feel this should be considered as one part of Sqoop's features.

Answer (score 2):

I think the blog http://www.tanzirmusabbir.com/2013/05/chunk-data-import-incremental-import-in.html might give you some hints.

Basically, it keeps the startindex and chunksize in the job.properties, and the startindex is used in where condition in Sqoop job, then it changes the startindex via shell script after the sqoop job.

Comment: The documents mentioned in the blog are not accessible.